# Creating a progress screen for MATLAB distributed computing applications

Tags: matlab, user-interface, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

I'm running a highly-parallelized MATLAB application on a cluster. I'm going to build a wait screen for the user and I'd like to display the progress of the cluster job. Here's some context:

```
clusterHandle = findResource(...);
jobHandle = createJob(clusterHandle);
% 'Do some setup stuff for the job...'
submit(jobHandle);
WaitFunction(jobHandle);

WaitFunction(jobHandle)

    while (~doneflag)

        % 'Your advice goes here...'

        doneflag = strcmp(jobHandle.State, 'finished');

    end

end
```

My question is: In what ways can I manipulate the jobHandle struct and it's fields to generate the percent completion of the job? The tasks in the job all have approximately the same runtime. For bonus rep: I'm also interested in information about/links to any interesting formats for wait screens. The only constrain on your advice and ideas is that the solution can't be excessively slow. Thanks!

Comment: I have used the matlab [waitbar](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/waitbar.html) before and it is very nice.

Comment: If all the jobs take approximately the same time then you can use the difference between the start and end of the first job to simply estimate the time of the next jobs. You could then update the timing with the average of the time all jobs have taken as processing continues. I can write this up into an answer if you would like. [job properties](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parallel.job.html)

Comment: Thanks for the waitbar suggestion. You are welcome to write it up.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the first job to estimate the time of all the remaining jobs.

```
% //Setup the wait bar
firstjob=true;
hw=waitbar(0,'Calculating Important cluster stuff',...
             'Name','Cluster Job',...
             'CreateCancelBtn',...
             'setappdata(gcbf,''canceling'',1)');
setappdata(hw,'canceling',0);
times=nan(numjobs);
clusterHandle = findResource(...);
jobHandle = createJob(clusterHandle);
% //'Do some setup stuff for the job...'
for i=1:num_jobs
    % //Add a stoping condition for the cancel button
    if getappdata(hw,'canceling')
        break;
    end
    % //if a job has completed update the runtime
    if ~firstjob
        waitbar(i/num_jobs,hw,sprintf('%2.0f %% Complete: Approx %d minutes remain',100*i/num_jobs,round(nanmean(times)/60)));
    end
    submit(jobHandle);
    WaitFunction(jobHandle);
    firstjob=false;
    % //This will be in seconds
    times(i) = etime(jobHandle.endTime,jobHandle.startTime);
end
```

With your waitfunction being the same as above